# After my app opens a file, keep a reference to the file so that I can open it again later

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have [registered my app to open audio files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application). I want to keep those files in my app indefinitely, though, even after the app is closed. Later on, I want to let the user play back any and all of the files that have ever been opened in the app.

How can I allow program my app to remember which files were opened in it in the past and handle them without asking other apps' permissions?

Comment: I asked a professor for his advice, and he suggested using [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/reference/reference.html) to take the files that other apps tell mine to open, and copy them into my app's private document directory. If that approach works well for me, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Read up on security scoped bookmarks, far better than copying the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to "handle them without asking other apps' permissions". Indeed, your app *never* had the ability to look into some other app's sandbox - that would violate the whole point of sandboxing. By the time your app is notified to open a handed-off file, the file has already been copied (by the system) into the Inbox folder of your Documents directory.

And there it remains (if you don't delete it yourself). So there's no problem accessing it. The reference that the system gave you when it notified you continues to work! Of course you are free to copy it elsewhere within the sandbox at that point. But the point is, it's already in your sandbox, and you already have a working reference to it.

(But watch out if your app implements "file sharing" thru iTunes ["Application supports iTunes file sharing", `UIFileSharingEnabled`], since in that case it is the Documents directory that is exposed thru iTunes, and thus a *user* can delete a file from the Inbox.)

Comment: iTunes doesn't show the contents of the Inbox. The real danger is that the user could delete the whole Inbox through iTunes.